# Broadcom SFP+ Card not listed in ifconfig at boot (FreeNAS)

Tags: freebsd, freenas

We are attempting to get a new FreeNAS storage array setup and working. The server has an add in NIC twoo bring us up to dual 10gbps connections.

When we boot the box, the add in NIC is not listed when we run `ifconfig`

running `ifconfig bxnt0` immediately makes the card available and we are able to further configure the card. We have attempted to configure the NIC through the web interface once it's detected and have also attempted to add the relevant `ifconfig_bnxt0="DHCP"` and `ifconfig_bnxt1=10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0` entries to `/etc/rc.local` but these configurations do not seem active after a reboot.

My experience here is in the Linux universe so I'm coming up blank on what to try next in the BSD world. any suggestions?

Comment: Broadcom does not supply drivers for FreeBSD.

Comment: That seems to be irrelevant. The nics are detected and work. We just have to run ```ifconfig bxnt0``` before they start working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the exact same issue here, just in another environment (OPNsense 22.1.8 at FreeBSD 13.0).

What helped: add the following line to `/boot/loader.conf` (or `.local`, etc):

```
if_bnxt_load="YES"
```

Comment: When an answer wasn't forth coming and we were getting further behind, the vendor suggested that switch to Ubuntu as the host OS so that is the state it is in now but this does sound like an entirely plausible solution. If we buy another storage array from this vendor maybe we'll give this a shot.